# How can I execute SpatiaLite commands directly from the command line?

Tags: spatialite, shell

I know I can open a SpatiaLite database and export a CSV from it as the following:

```
.headers on
.mode csv
.output csvFile.csv
select * from table
.output stdout
```

However, I'd like to automate the process of exporting CSV files from SpatiaLite with a bash script. Is there any way to execute this same sequence of commands from a shell? Just so I don't need to manually enter the database all the times I want to export data from it?

Alternatively, is there any way of exporting the result of a query inside my SpatiaLite database to a csv file directly? Without the need of using the commands that I used in my example?

Comment: sqlite3 should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @wingnut I guess in sqlite3 the procedure would be the same... But it's not clear to me how I can do it.

Comment: https://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/tool/ shows some command line options. Maybe try reading this first and having a few attempts.

Comment: @wingnut Cool, it accepts the query as its second parameter after the database name. So the solution was simple: `spatialite data.sqlite "select * from table" > file.csv`... The only remaining issue is a way of including the header on the file without using `.headers on`. Although I can do it directly on the shell before writing the data to the file.

Comment: See answer below. Headers and CSV are command line options.  https://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/tool/ shows this further down the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash, you can feed a series of lines to the stdin of a process using a "here document":

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlite3 test.db <<EOF
.headers on
.mode csv
select 1 as x, 2 as y, 3 as z;
EOF
```

which goes:

```
$ ./test.sh 
x,y,z
1,2,3
```

Everything between `<<EOF` and the `EOF` is fed to the process, as if you typed it. You can also put variables inside the document and expand them from the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

firstname=$1

sqlite3 test.db <<EOF
.headers on
.mode csv
select 1 as $firstname, 2 as y, 3 as z;
EOF
```

then you can do:

```
$ ./test.sh this
this,y,z
1,2,3
```

This is all standard Bash programming stuff, nothing special to `spatialite` here (I'm using sqlite3 but it will work in spatialite, I wasn't sure I had it installed). Consult a bash programming guide for more.

Answer (score 2):

```
spatialite -header -csv data.sqlite "select * from table" > file.csv
```